# Vuelidate reset specific field so that $error flag is false

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuelidate

Using Vuelidate you can reset the validation errors by using `this.$v.$reset()`. In this [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/bdoubleu/pen/abzreRj?editors=1010) resetting the `lastName` field that uses a Vuetify component works - `$invalid` is true while `$error` is set to false.

When resetting the regular text input for `firstName` it doesn't work as the `$error` flag is still true. How can I modify the text input so that $error is false when calling reset?

I've also tried `this.$nextTick(() => {...})` but that doesn't work either.

```js
Vue.use(window.vuelidate.default)
var validationMixin = window.vuelidate.validationMixin
const {
  maxLength,
  required
} = window.validators

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mixins: [validationMixin],
  data: () => ({
    form: {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: ''
    }
  }),
  validations: {
    form: {
      firstName: {
        required, maxLength: maxLength(2)
      },
      lastName: {
        required, maxLength: maxLength(2)
      },
    }
  }
})
```

```css
input.raw {
  border: solid;
}

.is-invalid {
  border-color: #FF5252 !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuelidate@0.6.1/dist/validators.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuelidate@0.6.1/dist/vuelidate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
            <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
            <input
              v-model="form.firstName"
              id="firstName"
              class="raw"
              :class="{ 'is-invalid': $v.form.firstName.$error }"
              type="text"
              width="100%"
              :oninput="$v.form.firstName.$touch()"
              :onblur="$v.form.firstName.$touch()"
            />
            <button @click="$v.form.firstName.$touch()">
              $touch
            </button>
            <button @click="$v.form.firstName.$reset()">
              $reset
            </button>
            <pre>{{ $v.form.firstName }}</pre>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure why, but it seems to make a difference when you use `@input` and `@blur` instead of `:oninput` and `:onblur`.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you are using `oninput` and `onblur` HTML attributes, but in Vue, you should use `@input`(`v-on:input`) and `@blur`(`v-on:blur`) bindings instead. See [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) for details.

Replacing HTML attributes with Vue bindings made your example work correctly:

```js
Vue.use(window.vuelidate.default)
var validationMixin = window.vuelidate.validationMixin
const {
  maxLength,
  required
} = window.validators

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mixins: [validationMixin],
  data: () => ({
    form: {
      firstName: '',
      lastName: ''
    }
  }),
  validations: {
    form: {
      firstName: {
        required, maxLength: maxLength(2)
      },
      lastName: {
        required, maxLength: maxLength(2)
      },
    }
  }
})
```

```css
input.raw {
  border: solid;
}

.is-invalid {
  border-color: #FF5252 !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuelidate@0.6.1/dist/validators.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuelidate@0.6.1/dist/vuelidate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
            <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
            <input
              v-model="form.firstName"
              id="firstName"
              class="raw"
              :class="{ 'is-invalid': $v.form.firstName.$error }"
              type="text"
              width="100%"
              @input="$v.form.firstName.$touch()"
              @blur="$v.form.firstName.$touch()"
            />
            <button @click="$v.form.firstName.$touch()">
              $touch
            </button>
            <button @click="$v.form.firstName.$reset()">
              $reset
            </button>
            <pre>{{ $v.form.firstName }}</pre>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -3):

This is Issue From Vuelidate and they must be fixed, in this position you can not reset form and give same (badly) behavior you can re-render by the router

```js
// re render component for reset all fileds
this.$router.go(0)
```

Comment: If this is a Vuelidate bug, consider adding a link to a related Github issue.